# css margin issue with jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've having an issue with the background images i have embedded into my carousel. [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/index.php) I've noticed when i click from one slide to another the background image on my site moves out of place. The margin-top for my carousel is current set to `margin-top:-275px;` and the background image is set to `margin-top:-64px;` I am slight concerned about these settings.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

In order to activate the slides click the thin red tab under the nav bar

Comment: @Oriol click on the thin red tab under the navigation bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's because you have

```
.rslides li {
  top:0;
}
```

It does nothing with `position:relative` (and the current slide has it), but it moves down the slide with `position:absolute` (hidden slides).

When you click a tab, there's a moment in which the new one is fading in, but it doesn't have `position:relative` yet. Then, in that moment, the new slide isn't where you want.

So remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

The jumping is occurring because you are switching the `LI` items from `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` at the end of the animation toggle. This can be avoided by removing your CSS rule:

`.rslides li { left: 0; top: 0; }`

Specifying `width` and `height` is fine, but as soon as you specify `left` and `top` - then switch from relative to absolute positioning, you get that jump you're seeing.

As for the positioning of each panel - it has to do with the way you are laying out your boxes. The sizes you are specifying are not large enough for the content you are providing. For instance: `<div id="header">` is `37px` tall, which is the appropriate size for the social media buttons, but you also have it as the container for the `#nav-menu` `UL` - which is another `102px` tall.

It appears that in order to correct this and make things overlap, you are using negative margins - which is getting you all thrown off.

My suggestion would be to use a standardized layout system, such as any of the following:

- http://cssgrid.net/
- http://960.gs/
- http://www.1kbgrid.com/
- http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php

And use it to perform your layout tasks, rather than trying to self-craft overlapping layers with mixed absolute/relative positioning.

Alternatively, if you're going to go the overlapping layers route (again, not suggested), really commit to it. Position things absolutely throughout the layout.

In order to accomplish this, you might consider CSS rules like:

```
#header {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    left: 50%; top: 0px;
    height: 139px; /* Your Social media links height + nav buttons height */
    width: 1018px; /* Your current width */
    margin-left: -509px; /* Half the width - centers on page */
}
```

Again - this is MUCH more work, MUCH harder to maintain and MUCH less elegant - but will yield you at least a consistent spacing / sizing.

Comment: i'm actually using html 5 boilerplate

Comment: Yes - I see that... you do realize that html5boilerplate doesn't contain a grid system, right? Foundation, though, contains both html5boilerplate in its entirety, and has a very elegant grid system. Hence my suggestion.